# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list - в чём может быть проблема? Как искать причину?

Tags: javascript

При запуске функции через onclick=""

В консоли выходит ошибка "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list". Ссылка в консоли на первую строку документа. Я точно знаю, что шибка возникает из за запуска этой функции. Ниже привожу, как это выглядит.

Кусок элемента с запуском функции startWf()

```
'<a class="dropdown-item" onclick="startWf(' + CompanyId + ',' + tplId + ',' + ValIdCompany + ',' + ValIdList + ',' + ValIdListElement + ',' + Object.values(listTech[i][nameObjModel])[0] + ',' + Object.values(listTech[i][nameObjVin])[0] + ',' + Object.values(listTech[i][nameObjModelDvig])[0] + ',' + Object.values(listTech[i][nameObjModelSnDvig])[0] + ',' + Object.values(listTech[i][nameObjModelGod])[0] + ',' + Object.values(listTech[i][nameObjModelNarab])[0] + ');">Сервис</a>';
```

Сама функция startWf()

```
function startWf(comId, tplsId, IdLists, IdListElements, PrmObjModel, prmObjVin, PrmObjModelDvig, PrmObjModelSnDvig, PrmObjModelGod, PrmObjModelNarab) {
    if (!comId) {
        alert('Нет id компании');
        return;
    }

    var params = {
        TEMPLATE_ID: tplsId,
        DOCUMENT_ID: ['crm', 'CCrmDocumentCompany', comId],
        PARAMETERS: {
            'IdCompany': comId,
            'IdList': IdLists,
            'IdListElement': IdListElements,
            'ValObjModel': PrmObjModel,
            'ValObjVin': prmObjVin,
            'ValObjModelDvig': PrmObjModelDvig,
            'ValObjModelSnDvig': PrmObjModelSnDvig,
            'ValObjModelGod': PrmObjModelGod,
            'ValObjModelNarab': PrmObjModelNarab,
        },
    };

    BX24.callMethod(
        'bizproc.workflow.start',
        params,
        function (result) {
            if (result.error())
                alert("Error: " + result.error());
            else
                alert("Success: " + result.data());
        }
    );
}
```

Вот так выглядит сформированный HTML-кусок.

```
<a class="dropdown-item" onclick="startWf(16132, 358, 116, 50736, Оборудованиt ODYN, VIN-123451234, DVIG-PODVIG-435, CY-1232323, 1996, 12345);">Сервис</a>
```

Рядом есть аналогичная функция с 2-мя параметрами, всё работает. Проблем нет.

```
'<a href="#" onclick="deleteElemList(' + listTech[i].IBLOCK_ID + ', ' + listTech[i].ID + ');" class=""></a>'
```

Функция deleteElemList()

```
function deleteElemList(blockId, elementId) {

    var params = {
        'IBLOCK_TYPE_ID': 'lists',
        'IBLOCK_ID': blockId,
        'ELEMENT_ID': elementId
    };
    BX24.callMethod(
        'lists.element.delete',
        params,
        function (result) {
            if (result.error())
                alert("Error: " + result.error());
            else
                alert("Success: " + result.data());
        }
    );

}
```

Вот сформированный кусок HTML. Не вижу разницы, но запуск первой функции выдает ошибку.

```
<a href="#" onclick="deleteElemList(116, 50736);" class=""></a>
```

Comment: Строки должны быть в кавычках.

Comment: @Yaant, уточните, пожалуйста, в каких кавычках? У меня всё, что выводится как строка - заключено в одинарные кавычки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По вашим словам
Js Генерирует вот такой код HTML

```
<a class="dropdown-item" onclick="startWf(16132, 358, 116, 50736, Оборудованиt ODYN, VIN-123451234, DVIG-PODVIG-435, CY-1232323, 1996, 12345);">Сервис</a>
```

А этот HTML при клике выполняет следующий код JS

```
startWf(16132, 358, 116, 50736, Оборудованиt ODYN, VIN-123451234, DVIG-PODVIG-435, CY-1232323, 1996, 12345);
```

Как вы видите кавычек (которые должны преобразовывать элементы в строку) нет. В этом и ошибка, если вы замените все аргументы функции, на числа вы не получите эту ошибку.

Я вам советую вместо onclick="" использовать полноценный метод в js element.addEveintListener();

Comment: Понял Вас. Спасибо большое. Буду пробовать этот метод.

Answer (score 0):

попробуй в функции **startWf()** закрывать и открывать однотипными скобками (или `'` или `"`, не совмещая)

вот так например

````
<a class="dropdown-item" onclick="startWf(" + CompanyId + ',' + tplId + ',' + ValIdCompany + ',' + ValIdList + ',' + ValIdListElement + ',' + Object.values(listTech[i][nameObjModel])[0] + ',' + Object.values(listTech[i][nameObjVin])[0] + ',' + Object.values(listTech[i][nameObjModelDvig])[0] + ',' + Object.values(listTech[i][nameObjModelSnDvig])[0] + ',' + Object.values(listTech[i][nameObjModelGod])[0] + ',' + Object.values(listTech[i][nameObjModelNarab])[0] + ");">Сервис</a>```
````